# My Page Control UI is not getting updated?

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol

My page control UI is not getting updated. The page control number is getting updated every time, but it's not being updated in the Page Control UI. I thought maybe using updateCurrentPageDisplay would work, or that was what I was missing, but I just received an error. Here is my code. Am I missing something that's need to update the UI?

```
@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!


  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

collection.delegate = self
collection.dataSource = self

    thisWidth = CGFloat(collection.frame.width)
    pageControl.hidesForSinglePage = true

    pageControl = UIPageControl.appearance()
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.red
    pageControl.numberOfPages = 10
    pageControl.currentPage = 0

  }
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 10
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CalanderCollectionViewCell

    let imagePath = array[indexPath.section]


    cell.configureCell(properties: imagePath)

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.pageControl.currentPage = indexPath.section
    print("current page\(pageControl.currentPage)")
    pageControl.updateCurrentPageDisplay()
    print(indexPath.section)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    thisWidth = CGFloat(collection.frame.width)
    return CGSize(width: thisWidth, height: collection.frame.height)
}
```

Comment: The top portion of the code seems incomplete.  At least one missing function.

Comment: Are u talking about the collectionview? I don't think so, which function am I missing?

Comment: `thisWidth` to `pageControl.currentPage = 0` aren't wrapped in a method.  I just don't understand where they exist in the file.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just copy and pasted that part. I forgot to show my viewDidLoad. They are are in ViewDidLoad.

Comment: I'm just statically setting the currentPage and numberOfPages so I get the in initial appearance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete this line:

```
pageControl = UIPageControl.appearance()
```

Comment: was that honestly it!! Thank You.